# Hide css dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've created a dropdown menu in css. My problem is that the dropdown is fixed on mobile phone if i touch somewhere outside the menu. How can i hide my dropdown menu on mobile phone? On desktop with mouse it works fine.

here is my css:

```css
#nav {
 margin: 0;
 text-align:center;
 position:fixed;
 width:1162px;
 top: 0%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -587px; /* Die Hälfte der Breite (width) + 6px */
 padding: 7px 6px 0;
 background: #7d7d7d url(img/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 -110px;
 line-height: 100%;

 border-radius: 1em;
 -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
 -moz-border-radius: 1em;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
}
#nav li {
 margin: 0 5px;
 padding: 0 0 8px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
}


/* main level link */
#nav a {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #e7e5e5;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding:  8px 20px;
 margin: 0;

 -webkit-border-radius: 1.6em;
 -moz-border-radius: 1.6em;
 
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
}
#nav a:hover {
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
}

/* main level link hover */
#nav .current a, #nav li:hover > a {
 background: #666 url(img/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 -40px;
 color: #444;
 border-top: solid 1px #f8f8f8;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);

 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 1);
}

/* sub levels link hover */
#nav ul li:hover a, #nav li:hover li a {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 color: #666;

 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
 background: #0078ff url(img/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 -100px !important;
 color: #fff !important;

 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0;

 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

/* dropdown */
#nav li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}

/* level 2 list */
#nav ul {
 display: none;

 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 185px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 35px;
 left: 0;
 background: #ddd url(img/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 0;
 border: solid 1px #b4b4b4;

 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
}
#nav ul li {
 float: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#nav ul a {
 font-weight: normal;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

/* level 3+ list */
#nav ul ul {
 left: 185px;
 top: -1px;
}

/* rounded corners of first and last link */
#nav ul li:first-child > a {
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 9px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 9px;

 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 9px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 9px;
}
#nav ul li:last-child > a {
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 9px;

 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 9px;
}

/* clearfix */
#nav:after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
 line-height: 0;
 height: 0;
}
#nav {
 display: inline-block;
} 
html[xmlns] #nav {
 display: block;
}
 
* html #nav {
 height: 1%;
}
```

and here the navigation menu set with ul and li

```html
<ul id="nav">
 <li class="current"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Musik</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 ul { display:block; padding:0px;}
 ul li{ display: inline-block; position:relative;}
 ul li ul { display:none; position:absolute; top:100%; left:0;}
 ul li ul li { display:block;}
 ul li ul li ul { left:100%; top:0;}
 ul li:hover > ul { display:block; width:120px;}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li>
         <a href="#">Menu option</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Menu option2</a>
            <ul>
             <li>
                 <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Submenu</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Submenu</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

If you are using hover property to show drop-down menu on desktop then it's automatically hidden on mobile when you touch outside the menu

Comment: but my menu doesnt hidden on iphone if i touch outside, thats my problem